# CsvHelper - Populating datatable slow(ish)

Tags: c#, performance, datatable, csvhelper

Have put together the code below to read a particular set of CSV files.  It works but is very much a work in progress.  There is one section of the code (populating datatable row - see snip below) that is taking as long to run as the SqlBulkCopy operation.  Asking for advice/recommendations on how to improve performance.

In the code (below) processing a ~15M row file in 50K batches took just under 11.5 minutes.  Breaking down the sections.  SqlBulkCopy took ~236Kms (4 min) the reader only needed 105Kms (~1.5min), and the section populating the datatable took ~200Kms (3.33 min).

```
     csvTableTimer.Start();
     // Process row and populate datatable
     DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
 
          foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
          {
               if (row.GetType().GetProperty(dc.ToString()).GetValue(row) != null)
               {
                    dr[dc.ToString()] = row.GetType().GetProperty(dc.ToString()).GetValue(row);
               }
           }
           dt.Rows.Add(dr);
 
      csvTableTimer.Stop();
```

The CSV files are very large (10+GB) and do not have headers.  I'm using the Class to build the datatable structure and like to continue with that approach when populating the datatable rows as I'll need to expand this to work with multiple CSV types.

The datatable reflects the column names from the class which line up with the SQL DB table.  Had wanted to use GetField (converted, not raw) walking each column in the datatable  `row[column.ColumnName] = csv.GetField( column.DataType, column.ColumnName );` but kept getting an error about there not being headers.  Found an open issue relating to HasHeaderRecord = false that matches up with what I was trying to do so that added to my desire to seek advice from those who are more skilled at this.  Appreciate the help!

Expanding on the code block;

```
     var rconfig = new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
     {
         BufferSize = 1024,
         Delimiter = ",",
         AllowComments = true,
         HasHeaderRecord = false,
         HeaderValidated = null,
         IgnoreBlankLines = true,
         MissingFieldFound = null,
         Comment = '#',
         Escape = '"',
         TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim,
         BadDataFound = x =>
         {
             isBadRecord = true;
             ErrRecords.Add(x.RawRecord);
             ++badCount;
         }
     };

     var loadFType = @"B";
     // Create datatable using class as definition.
     PropertyDescriptorCollection props1 = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(loaderFileType);
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     dt = UtilExtensions.CreateDataTable(props1);

     using (var reader = new StreamReader(rFile))
     {
         reader.ReadLine();
          
         using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, rconfig))
         {
             switch (loadFType)
             {
                 case "ALL":
                     csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<CSVLoader.AMap>();
                     var allRecords = new List<CSVLoader.A>();
                     break;
                 case "BAL":
                     csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<CSVLoader.BMap>();
                     var balRecords = new List<CSVLoader.B>();
                     break;

                 case "CIF":
                     csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<CSVLoader.CMap>();
                     var cifRecords = new List<CSVLoader.C>();
                     break;
             }

             dt.BeginLoadData();
             while (csv.Read())
             {
                 csvReadTimer.Start();
                 var row = csv.GetRecord(loaderFileType);
                 csvReadTimer.Stop();

                 runningCount++;

                 if (!isBadRecord)
                 {
                      csvTableTimer.Start();
                      // Process row and populate datatable
                      DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                      foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                      {
                          if (row.GetType().GetProperty(dc.ToString()).GetValue(row) != null)
                          {
                              dr[dc.ToString()] = row.GetType().GetProperty(dc.ToString()).GetValue(row);
                          }
                      }
                     dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                     csvTableTimer.Stop();
                     ++goodCount;

                     if (batchCount >= dtbatchSize || runningCount >= fileRecCount)
                     {
                         try
                         {
                             // Write from the source to the destination.
                             bcpLoadTimer.Start();

                             bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);

                             bcpLoadTimer.Stop();
                             bcpLoadBatchCount++;

                         }
                         catch (Exception ex)
                         {
                         }
                         dt.Clear();
                         batchCount = 0;
                     }
                     batchCount++;
                 }
                 isBadRecord = false;
             }
             dt.EndLoadData();
             reader.Close();
             dt.Clear();
             transaction.Commit();
```

```
// B
public class B
{
    [Index(0)]
    public string A { get; set; }
    [Index(1)]
    public string BString { get; set; }
    [Index(2)]
    public int? C { get; set; }
    [Index(3)]
    public string D { get; set; }
    [Index(4)]
    public string E { get; set; }
    [Index(5)]
    public DateTime? F { get; set; }
    [Index(6)]
    public decimal? G { get; set; }
    [Index(7)]
    public decimal? H { get; set; }
    [Index(8)]
    public decimal? I { get; set; }
    [Index(9)]
    public decimal? J { get; set; }
    [Index(10)]
    public int? K { get; set; }
    [Index(11)]
    public string L { get; set; }
    [Index(12)]
    public DateTime? M { get; set; }
}

// B
public sealed class BMap : ClassMap<B>
{
    public BMap()
    {
        // AutoMap(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Map(m => m.A).Index(0);
        Map(m => m.BString).Index(1); 
        Map(m => m.C).Index(2);
        Map(m => m.D).Index(3);
        Map(m => m.E).Index(4);
        Map(m => m.F).Index(5).TypeConverterOption.Format("yyyyMMdd");
        Map(m => m.G).Index(6);
        Map(m => m.H).Index(7);
        Map(m => m.I).Index(8);
        Map(m => m.J).Index(9);
        Map(m => m.K).Index(10);
        Map(m => m.L).Index(11);
        Map(m => m.M).Index(12).TypeConverterOption.Format("yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss.ffffff");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't suppose you could share a [mcve] could you?  I tried posting your code into a fiddle and got dozens of compilation errors, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/LLcWtw.

Comment: Sorry, was trying to not make to post too long.  Will post post a full run block.

Comment: A [mcve] isn't just a cut-and-paste of your entire code block, it is a ***minimal*** amount of code required to reproduce the problem.  For instance, I tried to simplify the `csvTableTimer` calculation as much as possible, see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UsUAgc.  Would you consider that to be a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't really include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so I simplified your code to create the following `FileLoader` class that times how long it takes to populate the `DataTable` from instances of some class `TClass` (here `B`) that had been read from a CSV row using `CsvReader`:

```
public class FileLoader
{
    public System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch csvTableTimer { get; } = new();

    public long Load<TClass, TClassMap>(string rFile, int dtbatchSize) where TClassMap : ClassMap<TClass>, new()
    {
        bool isBadRecord = false;
        long badCount = 0;
        long runningCount = 0;
        long goodCount = 0;
        long batchCount = 0;

        var rconfig = CreateCsvConfiguration(
            x => 
            {
                isBadRecord = true;
                //ErrRecords.Add(x.RawRecord);
                ++badCount;
            });
        
        // Create datatable using class as definition.
        var dt = UtilExtensions.CreateDataTable(typeof(TClass));

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(rFile))
        {
            //reader.ReadLine();  FIXED - THIS SKIPPED THE FIRST LINE AND CAUSED A RECORD TO BE OMITTED.
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, rconfig))
            {
                csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<TClassMap>();

                dt.BeginLoadData();
                while (csv.Read())
                {
                    isBadRecord = false;
                    //csvReadTimer.Start();
                    var record = csv.GetRecord<TClass>();
                    //csvReadTimer.Stop();

                    runningCount++;
                    if (!isBadRecord)
                    {
                        csvTableTimer.Start();
                        // Process row and populate datatable
                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            if (record.GetType().GetProperty(dc.ToString()).GetValue(record) != null)
                            {
                                dr[dc.ToString()] = record.GetType().GetProperty(dc.ToString()).GetValue(record);
                            }
                        }
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                        csvTableTimer.Stop();
                        goodCount++;
                        if (++batchCount >= dtbatchSize)
                        {
                            // Flush the data table
                            FlushTable(dt);
                            batchCount = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                dt.EndLoadData();
                FlushTable(dt);
                Commit();
            }
        }
        
        return goodCount;
    }

    protected virtual void FlushTable(DataTable dt) => dt.Clear();  // Replace with SqlBulkCopy 
    protected virtual void Commit() {} // Replace with transaction.Commit();
    
    public static CsvConfiguration CreateCsvConfiguration(BadDataFound badDataFound) => 
        new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        {
            BufferSize = 1024,
            Delimiter = ",",
            AllowComments = true,
            HasHeaderRecord = false,
            HeaderValidated = null,
            IgnoreBlankLines = true,
            MissingFieldFound = null,
            Comment = '#',
            Escape = '"',
            TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim,
            BadDataFound = badDataFound,
        };
}

public static partial class UtilExtensions
{
    static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetSerializableProperties(this Type type) => 
        type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0 && p.CanRead && p.CanWrite && p.GetGetMethod() != null && p.GetSetMethod() != null);
    
    public static DataTable CreateDataTable(Type type)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (var p in type.GetSerializableProperties())
            dt.Columns.Add(p.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(p.PropertyType) ?? p.PropertyType);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Then, if I use the file loader and call `loader.Load<B, BMap>(rFile, 1000)` to read a CSV file with 5555 rows 20 times, it takes roughly 1049 ms on dotnetfiddle. See demo #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UsUAgc).

One problem you are encountering is that reflection in c# can be very slow.  You are calling `record.GetType().GetProperty(dc.ToString()).GetValue(record)` twice, and if I simply reduce the number of calls by 1, the time is reduced to around 706 ms:

```
                        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            var value = record.GetType().GetProperty(dc.ToString()).GetValue(record);
                            if (value != null)
                            {
                                dr[dc.ToString()] = value;
                            }
                        }
```

Demo #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HkyYw5).

However, we can do better by manufacturing a delegate in runtime.  First, add the following utility methods that make use of the [`System.Linq.Expressions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=net-5.0) namespace:

```
public static partial class UtilExtensions
{
    public static Func<TSource, object> CreatePropertyGetter<TSource>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "obj");
        var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyInfo);
        var convert = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<TSource, object>), convert, parameter);

        return (Func<TSource, object>)lambda.Compile();
    }

    public static ReadOnlyDictionary<string, Func<TSource, object>> PropertyGetters<TSource>() => PropertyExpressionsCache<TSource>.PropertyGetters;

    static ReadOnlyDictionary<string, Func<TSource, object>> CreatePropertyGetters<TSource>() =>
        typeof(TSource)
            .GetSerializableProperties()
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Name,
                          p => CreatePropertyGetter<TSource>(p))
            .ToReadOnly();

    static class PropertyExpressionsCache<TSource>
    {
        public static ReadOnlyDictionary<string, Func<TSource, object>> PropertyGetters { get; } = UtilExtensions.CreatePropertyGetters<TSource>();
    }
    
    public static ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToReadOnly<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary) => 
        new ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>(dictionary ?? throw new ArgumentNullException());
}
```

And modify `Load<TClass, TClassMap>()` as follows:

```
public long Load<TClass, TClassMap>(string rFile, int dtbatchSize) where TClassMap : ClassMap<TClass>, new()
{
    bool isBadRecord = false;
    long badCount = 0;
    long runningCount = 0;
    long goodCount = 0;
    long batchCount = 0;

    var rconfig = CreateCsvConfiguration(
        x => 
        {
            isBadRecord = true;
            //ErrRecords.Add(x.RawRecord);
            ++badCount;
        });
    
    var loaderFileType = typeof(TClass);

    // Create datatable using class as definition.
    var dt = UtilExtensions.CreateDataTable(loaderFileType);
    var properties = UtilExtensions.PropertyGetters<TClass>();

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(rFile))
    {
        //reader.ReadLine();  FIXED - THIS SKIPPED THE FIRST LINE AND CAUSED A RECORD TO BE OMITTED.
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, rconfig))
        {
            csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<TClassMap>();

            dt.BeginLoadData();
            while (csv.Read())
            {
                isBadRecord = false;
                //csvReadTimer.Start();
                var record = csv.GetRecord<TClass>();
                //csvReadTimer.Stop();

                runningCount++;
                if (!isBadRecord)
                {
                    csvTableTimer.Start();
                    // Process row and populate datatable
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    foreach (var p in properties)
                    {
                        var value = p.Value(record);
                        if (value != null)
                            dr[p.Key] =  value;
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    csvTableTimer.Stop();
                    goodCount++;
                    if (++batchCount >= dtbatchSize)
                    {
                        // Flush the data table
                        FlushTable(dt);
                        batchCount = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            dt.EndLoadData();
            FlushTable(dt);
        }
    }
    
    return goodCount;
}
```

The time will be further reduced, to roughly 404 ms.  Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/08IDgC).

I also tried using `Delegate.CreateDelegate()` instead of `Expression`:

```
public static partial class UtilExtensions
{
    static Func<TSource, object> CreateTypedPropertyGetter<TSource, TValue>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        var typedFunc = (Func<TSource, TValue>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<TSource, TValue>), propertyInfo.GetGetMethod());
        return i => (object)typedFunc(i);
    }

    public static Func<TSource, object> CreatePropertyGetter<TSource>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        var typedCreator = typeof(UtilExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(CreateTypedPropertyGetter), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var concreteTypedCreator = typedCreator = typedCreator.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TSource), propertyInfo.PropertyType);
        return (Func<TSource, object>)concreteTypedCreator.Invoke(null, new object [] { propertyInfo });
    }

    public static ReadOnlyDictionary<string, Func<TSource, object>> PropertyGetters<TSource>() => PropertyExpressionsCache<TSource>.PropertyGetters;

    static ReadOnlyDictionary<string, Func<TSource, object>> CreatePropertyGetters<TSource>() =>
        typeof(TSource)
            .GetSerializableProperties()
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Name,
                          p => CreatePropertyGetter<TSource>(p))
            .ToReadOnly();

    static class PropertyExpressionsCache<TSource>
    {
        public static ReadOnlyDictionary<string, Func<TSource, object>> PropertyGetters { get; } = UtilExtensions.CreatePropertyGetters<TSource>();
    }
    
    public static ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToReadOnly<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary) => 
        new ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>(dictionary ?? throw new ArgumentNullException());
}
```

And got roughly the same time, of 410 ms.  Demo fiddle #4 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RIoXmi).

Notes:

- The code in your question skips the first line of the CSV file, by calling `reader.ReadLine();`.

  In my test harness this caused an incorrect number of records to be read, so I removed this line.
- Rather than having a non-generic method that has a switch on the record type, I extracted a generic method that takes the record type and class map type as generic parameters.  This makes delegate creation a little easier as it is no longer necessary to do runtime casting to the record type.

Comment: dbc, As is so blatantly obvious by my code, I am very green when it comes to C#.  Can't thank you enough for your time and detail.  Will take me a bit to learn from what you've provided.  Regarding the 2 notes at the bottom, the reader.ReadLine() is to skip a file header that that used by a separate process (no column headers).  The switch on record type, that is pretty much exactly what I was hoping to learn.  TY again!

Comment: @MrAC - you're welcome.  If the `TClass` type is based on the file extension, you could switch on the extension at the very top level of your code, then call the generic with the appropriate `<TClass, TClassMap>`.  Let us know how much this time this saves loading your real CSVs.  Then if the question is answered, please do [mark it as such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147531).

Comment: Sorry haven't been able to close this just yet.  Kinda hectic.  The one line change in scenario datatable row population ``var value = record.GetType().GetProperty(dc.ToString()).GetValue(record);`` resulting in a 14% improvement.  8.73M rows went from 20Krps to 24Krps will all of the time gain being in the loop.  Implementing the Linq solution requires a bit more work and learning on my part.  Working on it now between support calls.  Will post results (timings) mark the case as quickly as I can.  Thanks again.

Comment: One last update thank @dbc for the great input and detail.  The 2 biggest changes that I ended up making was reducing reflection and then running the bulk copy async.